# Sublime text find & replace retain wildcard value

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Seems simple but I can't get the right syntax.

I want to add chars after a string occurrance
where line begins with K: then wildcard for one or more chars before end of line

***sample case***

`K:G` -> `K:G",`

or

`K:Ador` -> `K:Ador",`

***FIND***: `K:+[A-Za-z]+$`

***REPLACE***: `K:+[A-Za-z]+",$`

When I run this, the result clears the actual values and replaces with the literal regex values- giving me `K:+[A-Za-z]+",$` which is not what I want

How can I retain the wildcard values after replace?

Comment: Wrap the part you need to keep with `(` and `)`, and then use `$1` to put it back in the replacement pattern. Replacement patterns != regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks that worked, and noted on the replacement patterns!
find: K:+(\w+)$. 
replace with: K:$1","

Comment: Or, you might also use `K:+[A-Za-z]+$` and replace with `$0",`.